# How to configure optional tags for Terraform AWS Inspector Resource Group?

Tags: security, terraform

The AWS console for Inspector allows filtering targeted EC2 instances by tag, or selecting all instances.

In our multi account setup, not all accounts will use instance tagging, and not all tagged instances will have the same key and value, or even the same key.

When setting up the Inspector configuration through Terraform, how can the `tags` property of `aws_inspector_resource_group` be externalized for a reusable module such that every account can either pass in either an empty map or tag(s) used within that account?

Thanks.